# Nested loop to return simple ListItem in Reactjs - -Object.values and Object.keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, array.prototype.map

Really stumped. I am trying to create a `ListItem` for every key of every value in an array of objects. When I log `item`, it returns the key I'm looking for as a string. Great! However, the list items never render on the page.

```js
return (
 <div>
  <List className="list">
   {Object.values(props.sectionInfo).forEach(section => {
   Object.keys(section).map((item, index) => {
    return (
     <ListItem button className='list-item'> //doesn't render, but also doesn't throw errors
      <ListItemText primary={item} />
     </ListItem>
     )
   });
  })}
  </List>
 </div>
);

console.log(item) //returns "red", "blue"
```

The below renders the list perfectly, however the list items are the indexes (0, 1)

```
return (
 <div>
  <List className="list">
   {Object.keys(props.sectionInfo).map((section, index) => {
    return (
     <ListItem button className='list-item'>
      <ListItemText primary={section} />
     </ListItem>
    )
   })}
  </List>
 </div>
);
```

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using the `forEach` in the outer loop and it doesn't return anything actually, so the `children` prop of the `List` is `undefined`. Try this:

```js
return (
 <div>
  <List className="list">
   {Object.values(props.sectionInfo).map(section => {
   return Object.keys(section).map((item, index) => {
    return (
     <ListItem button className='list-item'>
      <ListItemText primary={item} />
     </ListItem>
     )
   });
  })}
  </List>
 </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to build list of virtual doms as following:

```
let items = []
Object.values(props.sectionInfo).forEach(section => {
   let subItems = Object.keys(section).map((item, index) => {
    return (
     <ListItem button className='list-item'> //doesn't render, but also doesn't throw errors
      <ListItemText primary={item} />
     </ListItem>
     )
   });

   items = items.concat(subItems);
  })

return (
 <div>
  <List className="list">
   {items}
  </List>
 </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going through `Object.values(section)` in the second loop?

Because from your second statement it seems like the contents are indexed as an Array. Maybe you can give more information about the data structure to help you further.